# WordPress - Optimize the Meta Query for 3 meta keys at a time

Tags: wordpress, optimization

##### Records in `post_meta` as follow:

| post_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | price | 10 |
| 1 | price_to | 5000 |
| 2 | price_type | 'POA' |
| 3 | price | 12000 |
| 3 | price_to | 17000 |
| 4 | price | 1200 |
| 4 | price_to | 8000 |
| 5 | price_type | 'POA' |

##### Code Snippet

```
<?php
$price_from = '20';
$price_to = '700';

$meta_query_price[] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value'    =>  $price_from,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price_to',
            'value'    =>  $price_to,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare'  => '>='
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'price_type',
        'value'    =>  'POA',
        'type'    =>  'value',
        'compare'  => 'LIKE'
    ),
);
```

##### Output

| post_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | price | 10 |
| 1 | price_to | 5000 |
| 2 | price_type | 'POA' |
| 5 | price_type | 'POA' |

Above code is executed perfectly issue is when I add `price_type` to the meta_query to extend data it will cause the speed issue.
The result come perfect but time will be very high.

> So, is there any tricks to do this kind of query in WordPress?

Comment: Try [adding database keys to your postmeta table](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/). But be aware that OR queries aren't super fast.

Comment: @O.Jones I have tried that plugin still found same speed issue. Please have a look once I have altered code and it's worked fine. Why that happening exactly not understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Conclusion - In my case I tried below

When I changed placement of last meta or at the first place worked perfectly.

```
<?php
$price_from = '20';
$price_to = '700';

$meta_query_price[] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'price_type',
        'value'    =>  'POA',
        'type'    =>  'value',
        'compare'  => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value'    =>  $price_from,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price_to',
            'value'    =>  $price_to,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare'  => '>='
        ),
    ),
);
```